# heroku/rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am following Hartl's tutorial and am having trouble pushing to heroku after chapter 5.  I am getting the error "We're sorry, something went wrong. And I have read 10-15 other stackoverflow questions about it and none of their solutions helped me.  I have run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I have included my heroku log errors and Gemfile beolow.  Thanks!

```
    2013-03-05T16:02:17+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Starting process with command `bundle exec            rake db:migrate`
    2013-03-05T16:02:17+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Awaiting client
    2013-03-05T16:02:17+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-03-05T16:02:21+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
    2013-03-05T16:02:22+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Process exited with status 0
    2013-03-05T16:02:22+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: State changed from up to complete
    .
    .
    .
    2013-03-05T16:15:23+00:00 heroku[run.8755]: Awaiting client
    2013-03-05T16:15:23+00:00 heroku[run.8755]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:drop`
    2013-03-05T16:15:23+00:00 heroku[run.8755]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-03-05T16:15:25+00:00 heroku[run.8755]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
    2013-03-05T16:15:27+00:00 heroku[run.8755]: State changed from up to complete
    2013-03-05T16:15:27+00:00 heroku[run.8755]: Process exited with status 0
    2013-03-05T16:16:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by zyskowski.rob@gmail.com
    2013-03-05T16:16:03+00:00 heroku[run.8187]: Awaiting client
    2013-03-05T16:16:03+00:00 heroku[run.8187]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2013-03-05T16:16:03+00:00 heroku[run.8187]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-03-05T16:16:09+00:00 heroku[run.8187]: Process exited with status 0
    2013-03-05T16:16:09+00:00 heroku[run.8187]: State changed from up to complete
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
end

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

after updating my Gemfile as above my heroku logs look nicer but I am still having the same problem.  Here are my most recent heroku logs:

```
    2013-03-05T16:21:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2013-03-05T16:21:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
    2013-03-05T16:21:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 16:21:25] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
    2013-03-05T16:21:32+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-03-05T16:21:32+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-03-05T16:21:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
    2013-03-05T16:21:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
    2013-03-05T16:21:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2013-03-05T16:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 16:21:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2013-03-05T16:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 16:21:39] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
    2013-03-05T16:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 16:21:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=28050
    2013-03-05T16:21:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-03-05T16:23:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2013-03-05T16:23:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:28050
    2013-03-05T16:23:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 173.28.201.119 at 2013-03-05 16:23:08 +0000
    2013-03-05T16:23:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2013-03-05T16:23:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (7.7ms)
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 82ms
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (15.1ms)
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled):
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>     
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!--[if lt IE 9]-->
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <!--[endif]-->
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb___2240892464821239054_34301780'
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3847180770533719708_34372820'
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T16:23:09+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=stark-mesa-9938.herokuapp.com fwd="173.28.201.119" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=823ms status=500 bytes=643
    2013-03-05T16:23:10+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stark-mesa-9938.herokuapp.com fwd="173.28.201.119" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=5ms connect=17ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=0
    2013-03-05T16:25:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 173.28.201.119 at 2013-03-05 16:25:55 +0000
    2013-03-05T16:25:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled):
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.7ms)
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!--[if lt IE 9]-->
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>     
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <!--[endif]-->
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb___2240892464821239054_34301780'
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3847180770533719708_34372820'
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=stark-mesa-9938.herokuapp.com fwd="173.28.201.119" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=6ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=643
    2013-03-05T16:25:56+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stark-mesa-9938.herokuapp.com fwd="173.28.201.119" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
    2013-03-05T17:30:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2013-03-05T17:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 17:30:27] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
    2013-03-05T17:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
    2013-03-05T17:30:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
    2013-03-05T17:30:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
    2013-03-05T17:30:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2013-03-05T17:30:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2013-03-05T18:07:49+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
    2013-03-05T18:09:15+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by zyskowski.rob@gmail.com
    2013-03-05T18:09:15+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b3805c8 by zyskowski.rob@gmail.com
    2013-03-05T18:09:15+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2013-03-05T18:09:16+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
    2013-03-05T18:09:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 14406`
    2013-03-05T18:09:23+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-03-05T18:09:23+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-03-05T18:09:31+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 18:09:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2013-03-05T18:09:31+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 18:09:31] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=14406
    2013-03-05T18:09:31+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-05 18:09:31] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
    2013-03-05T18:09:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-03-05T18:09:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 129.255.225.74 at 2013-03-05 18:09:38 +0000
    2013-03-05T18:09:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2013-03-05T18:09:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:14406
    2013-03-05T18:09:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2013-03-05T18:09:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2013-03-05T18:09:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (10.3ms)
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (17.1ms)
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 135ms
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled):
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!--[if lt IE 9]-->
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>     
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <!--[endif]-->
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=stark-mesa-9938.herokuapp.com fwd="129.255.225.74" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=4ms service=4384ms status=500 bytes=643
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb___158571620836036303_35162880'
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3114180369605444575_34223240'
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T18:09:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-03-05T18:09:42+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stark-mesa-9938.herokuapp.com fwd="129.255.225.74" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=10ms connect=46ms service=1187ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: Have you precompiled your assets on your local?

Comment: What do your `heroku logs` say?

Comment: Do you have a Procfile inside your application's root?

Comment: I have added my most recent heroku logs above after changing my Gemfile below

Comment: What is a Procfile?  I do not think that i have this...

Answer (score 1):

This is assets precompile problem, so please precompile assets in local and change the settings on environments for check precompile then deploy.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the second edition of the tutorial? If you are, this is my Gemfile for until chapter 7, exactly as recommended for the tutorials. Might be having incompatibilities?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments to your question so I'm asking here.

Are you following the latest edition of the book?

```
2013-03-05T18:09:23+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-05T18:09:23+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

hints that you are using vendor plugins. The current edition does not include usage of vendor plugins (as far as chapter 7 at least). If you are using an older edition, the syntex might have changed ever so slightly to cause incompatibility issues.

Please check the book edition before proceeding.

Comment: I am following the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial, I am not sure which edition, but I do not think it is the most up to date (it is behind the tutorial online).

Comment: If that is the case, using my Gemfile might not be compatible as well. Go through your edition of the book and follow each Gemfile change, including version numbers, and see how it fares.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the it's missing the precompiled assets. If you ran the command locally, you need to `git add .` and `git commit` the assets into the repo and then `git push heroku` again.

Also, Heroku's default build pack will try to precompile the assets during deploy, so you could try to figure out why that is failing.

You don't *need* to add a Procfile. Heroku will use reasonable defaults.